# Is the zero truncated Poisson Distribution part of the Exponential Family?

Tags: self-study, distributions, generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, exponential-family

This is the density of a truncated Poisson: 
$$P(X = x \mid X > 0) =  
\frac{\lambda ^ x e^{- \lambda} }{x ! \left ( 1 - e^{- \lambda} \right )}$$

To show that it's member of the Exponential family I have to bring it in this form:

Exponential family:

$ f(x, \theta, \phi) = exp ( \frac{ x \theta - b(\theta}{ a(\phi)} + c(x, \phi ))  $

if I do this for the Poisson distribution I get: $$ \theta = log \lambda \\ 
\lambda = e^\theta \\ b(\theta)= e^\theta \\ a(\phi)=1 \\ c(x,\phi)= -log(x!)$$
I struggle now with this extra term $ \frac{1}{1-e^{-\lambda}}$ from the truncated Poisson. Where does it belong to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My definition of an exponential family is a parameterised family of densities that factorises as [with respect to a given measure $\text{d}\lambda$]
$$\exp\{a(\theta)\cdot s(x)-\psi(\theta)\}h(x)$$
where $\psi(\cdot)$ is automatically defined as
$$\exp\{\psi(\theta)\}=\int_\mathcal X\exp\{a(\theta)\cdot s(x)\}h(x)\text{d}\lambda(x)$$
The family of truncated-at-zero Poissons has density [wrt the counting measure on $\Bbb N^*_+$ ]proportional to $\lambda^x/x!$ and the normalising constant is
$$\exp\{\psi(\lambda)\}=\sum_{x=1}^\infty \lambda^x/x! = \frac{1-e^{-\lambda}}{e^{-\lambda}}$$
so this is again an exponential family.

Answer (score 2):

The [typical](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Exponential_family#/Scalar_parameter), [formulation](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~jebara/4771/tutorials/lecture12.pdf) is 
$f_X(x|\theta)=h(x)\exp(\eta(\theta)T(x)-A(\theta))$, in your case we can arrange the PMF as 
$$f_\theta(x)=\underbrace{\frac{1}{x!}}_{h(x)}\exp(\underbrace{x}_{T(x)}\underbrace{\log \lambda}_{\eta(\theta)}-\underbrace{(\lambda+\log(1-e^{-\lambda}))}_{A(\theta)})$$

Here, we can state that $\theta=\lambda$, without loss of generality.